# How to reference "Automatic" Properties in my class?

Tags: c#, xna

The tutorial I'm following (http://www.bluerosegames.com/xna101/post/Lesson-9-Improving-the-BouncingBall-Class-Using-Properties.aspx)

```
private Vector2 _position;
public Vector2 Position
{
    get

    {
        return _position;
    }
    set
    {
        _position = value;
    }
}
```

does not use the automatic properties feature in the code. I'd like to skip most of the typing using the automatic properties but I have problems later on in the code. I've commented the lines below that are affected.

```
public Vector2 Position { get; set; }

    public void Update()
    {
        Position = Position + Velocity;

        if (Position.X < 0 || Position.X > GraphicsViewport.Width - Texture.Width)
        {
            // If we get in here, we've hit a vertical wall
            Velocity.X = -Velocity.X; // doesn't work
            Position.X = Position.X + Velocity.X; // doesn't work
        }
        if (Position.Y < 0 || Position.Y > GraphicsViewport.Height - Texture.Height)
        {
            // If we get in here, we've hit a horizontal wall
            Velocity.Y = -Velocity.Y; // doesn't work
            Position.Y = Position.Y + Velocity.Y; // doesn't work
        } 
    }
```

The error that I get in Visual Studio states that "Cannot modify the return value of WindowsGame1.BouncingBall.Position' because it is not a variable." So how can I get the code to work with the automatic properties?

Thank you!
John

Comment: Does this work even without the automatic property? Vector2 is a struct.

Comment: Yeah it works with the long version of the property and then in the Update method he references the private _position variable and it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exact question has already been [asked and answered](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32457954/cannot-modify-the-return-value-because-it-is-not-a-variable.aspx):

> This code isn't trying to do what you
>   think it's trying to do...
>
> Vector2 is a struct, so your call in
>   Update first *copies* Position onto
>   the stack, adds velocity.X to the new
>   Vector2's 'X' and then throws it away.
>   The original value was never modified.
>
> The C# compiler catches your mistake
>   in this case (phew!). You instead need
>   to do:
>
> Position = new
>   Vector2(Position.X+velocity.X,
>   Position.Y);
>
> The difference between value and
>   reference types is fundamental in C# -
>   the C# specification describes that
>   difference immediately after "hello,
>   world"
>
> See section 8.2 of the C#
>   specification for more information:
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf
>
> Alun Harford

Comment: No problem! Hit up Google next time for an even faster resolution :)